# Recursive traverse JSON with circe-optics

Tags: scala, circe

I have a `json` with complex structure. Something like this:

```
{
  "a":"aa",
  "b":"bb",
  "c":[
    "aaa",
    "bbb"
  ],
  "d":{
    "e":"ee",
    "f":"ff"
  }
}
```

And I want to uppercase all string values. [The Documentation](https://circe.github.io/circe/optics.html) says:

```
root.each.string.modify(_.toUpperCase)
```

But only root values are updated, as expected.

How to make `circe-optics` traverse all string values recursively?
`JSON` structure is unknown in advance.

Here is the [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m3BX15v3TaKK5y3mNQNILw) on Scastie.

---

via comments:
I am expecting all string values uppercased, not only root values:

```
{
  "a":"AA",
  "b":"BB",
  "c":[
    "AAA",
    "BBB"
  ],
  "d":{
    "e":"EE",
    "f":"FF"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show, what exactly the data result you want.

Comment: Your question is not that clear.

Comment: @Rex updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a partial solution, as in, it is not fully recursive, but it will solve the issue with the `json` from your example:

```scala
val level1UpperCase = root.each.string.modify(s => s.toUpperCase)

val level2UpperCase = root.each.each.string.modify(s => s.toUpperCase)
val uppered = (level1UpperCase andThen level2UpperCase)(json.right.get)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might be a new way to do this. Adding it here for completeness.

```scala
  import io.circe.Json
  import io.circe.parser.parse
  import io.circe.optics.JsonOptics._
  import monocle.function.Plated

  val json = parse(
    """
      |{
      |  "a":"aa",
      |  "b":"bb",
      |  "c":[
      |    "aaa",
      |    {"k": "asdads"}
      |  ],
      |  "d":{
      |    "e":"ee",
      |    "f":"ff"
      |  }
      |}
      |""".stripMargin).right.get
  val transformed = Plated.transform[Json] { j =>
    j.asString match {
      case Some(s) => Json.fromString(s.toUpperCase)
      case None    => j
    }
  }(json)

  println(transformed.spaces2)
```

gives

```
{
  "a" : "AA",
  "b" : "BB",
  "c" : [
    "AAA",
    {
      "k" : "ASDADS"
    }
  ],
  "d" : {
    "e" : "EE",
    "f" : "FF"
  }
}
```